# ios potential leak how to solve?

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-leaks, retaincount

I've analyzed my project:
and this is the result:
[image]

what means and how can I solve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should release `pdfURL` after you have used it to create `pdf`.

Try...

```
CGPDFDocumentRef pdf = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL(pdfURL);
CFRelease(pdfURL);
```

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you might want to familiarise yourself with the [Memory Management Programming Guide for Core Foundation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/CFMemoryMgmt.html), specifically the [ownership policy](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001148-CJBEJBHH).

In short, you have to `CFRelease()` the `pdfURL` object. :-)